# angular.js - share cacheFactory data between blocks

Tags: angularjs, caching

I want to share the same `$cacheFactory` between `.run` block and a service.
I defined a `$cacheFactory` in my `.run` block :

```
var cache = $cacheFactory('cacheName');
```

and put some stuff inside:

```
cache.put('appData', data);
```

then I want to check if the key exsits in one of my services but the error I get is - `CacheId 'CacheName' is already taken!`

Here is the service code:

```
$scope.cache = $cacheFactory('cacheName');
if (angular.isUndefined($scope.cache.get(key))) {
   $log.log($scope.cache.get(key)); //printing th key
}
```

so how do I share cache data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hard to say without seeing the rest of your code. But my example below works

```
(function(angular) {
  'use strict';

  angular
    .module('cacheExampleApp', [])
    .controller('CacheController', ['$scope', '$cacheFactory', 'notify', function($scope, $cacheFactory, notify) {

      $scope.cache = $cacheFactory('cacheName');
      $scope.cache.put('appData', 'some data');

      $scope.callNotify = function() {
        notify();
      };

    }])
    .factory('notify', ['$window', '$cacheFactory', function(win, $cacheFactory) {

      return function() {
        var dataCache = $cacheFactory.get('cacheName');
        win.alert(dataCache.get('appData'));
      };

    }]);

})(window.angular);
```

Example: https://plnkr.co/edit/axiPg5qzxLTyGLy8pMu1?p=preview

Comment: I should add that you can only inject instances (not Providers) into run blocks.  You may want to use a config block (which only accepts providers and not instances)

Comment: That was indeed the way to solve this, but I user a service that hold the data and not controller.

Answer (score 0):

So I used a `service` to store the data, service code:

```
(function () {
    'use strict';
    var cacheService = function ($log, $cacheFactory) {
        //define cache factory 
        var cache = $cacheFactory('cacheID');
        /*put key-val in cache*/
        var _putData = function(key, val){
            //check for undefined 
            if(!angular.isUndefined(key) && !angular.isUndefined(val)){
                //key must be a String
                if(angular.isString(key)){
                    cache.put(key, val);
                }else{
                    $log.error('Error in cacheService key must be a String type only!');    
                }

            }else{
                $log.error('Error in cacheService key or value are undefined');
            }
        };
        /*get data from cache */
        var _getData = function(key){
            //check for String type
            if(angular.isString(key)){
               return cache.get(key);
            }else{
                $log.error('Error in cacheService key must ne a String type');
            }
        };
        /*Get info */
        var _info = function(){
            return cache.info();
        };
        /*Remove data */
        var _remove = function(key){
            //check for String type
            if(angular.isString(key)){
                cache.remove(key);
            }else{
                $log.error('Error in cacheService key must ne a String type');
            }
        };
        /*clear cache*/
        var _removeAll = function(){
            cache.removeAll();
        };
        /*  PUBLIC API  */
        var service = {
            //model: _model,
            put : _putData,
            get : _getData,
            remove : _remove,
            removeAll : _removeAll
        };

        return service;

    };


    angular.module('common').service('cacheService', cacheService);


})();
```

Then I just simply inject it to wherever needed.